# Error in model.frame.default(..., drop.unused.levels = TRUE, : variable lengths differ (found for '(weights)')

Tags: r, data-modeling

I'll try to be quick. 
I am working on a longitudinal split plot study and I am facing a really hard time in modeling it.
Heights of 314 stumps were measured in two areas for 9 years (same individuals). each area had treatment plot and control plot. There were 3 species, two in an area and one in the other area.

data.frame':    1895 obs. of  5 variables:
 $ treatment: Factor w/ 2 levels "fenced","unfenced": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ stump    : Factor w/ 314 levels "210","211","212",..: 171 172 173 178 179 180 181 183 184 186 ...
 $ species  : Factor w/ 3 levels "CS","FO","QR": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ hmean    : num  140 130 85 150 170 90 70 135 105 95 ...
 $ days     : num  378 378 378 378 378 378 378 378 378 378 ...

My aim is to model *hmean* by using *treatment*, *species* and *days* as fixed effects and *stump* as random effect.
I have some issues in modelling because data are temporally correlated and the variance of my reponse variable *height* increases over the variable "days".

I tried this code:

```
vs <- varPower(form = ~ days)

glmmTMB(hmean ~ species*treatment*days + ar1(days | stump), 
                 family = Gamma(link = "log"), 
                 weights= vs,
                 data=data_hmean)
```

and it gave me this result:

```
Error in model.frame.default(data = data_hmean, weights = vs, drop.unused.levels = TRUE,  : 
  variable lengths differ (found for '(weights)')
```

How can I fix this problem? any suggestion?

Comment: where is vs from since you use it as weights? it should be the same length as the data.frame